# Image not rendering with express and ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am not very familiar with ejs and I am working on a practice project that uses it. Somehow it renders everything except the image. It is using an image from an express session, but I have tried even replacing it with the exact url and it still does not work.

Here is the app.js file

```
//Imports
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const partials = require('express-partials');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('./config/passport.js');

//Variables
const PORT = 3000;
const EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET = process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET;

//Remove after development to minimize unnecessary realtime logs on server
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

//Express setup
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.disable('x-powered-by');

//Express page setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(partials());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

//Express session set up to be used on all routes
app.use(
  session({
    secret: EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 *60 * 24 }
  })
);

//Initializes passport to be used on all routes
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


//Mounts the page router
const pageRouter = require('./routers/page-router.js');
app.use('/', pageRouter);

//Mounts the api router
const apiRouter = require('./routers/api-router.js');
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

//Starts server
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));
```

Here is the route which is in a router, the GET route to /account is the one of interest

```
//Imports necessary modules
const express = require('express');
const {ensureAuthenticated} = require('../middleware/auth-middleware.js');

//Creates the router
const pageRouter = express.Router();

//This page is protected and requires github authentication
pageRouter.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

//Exports the router
module.exports = pageRouter;
```

And finally here is the ejs file which is located in the views folder. All of the other data like the name and link populate correctly, I just cant get an image to render, even when using the actual url

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <h1><%= user.username %></h1>
    <p>ID: <%= user.id %></p>
    <p>Name: <%= user.displayName %></p>
    <p>Bio: <%= user._json.bio %></p>
    <p>GitHub: <a href="<%= user._json.html_url %>">Link</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="six columns">
    <img src="<%= user.photos[0].value %>" alt="Avatar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or guidance at all will be very appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the html from the source code, which seems valid and works on it's own. I have no clue why it's not rendering properly when served by my app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Codecademy OAuth Project</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <nav>
                
                    <div>
                        <a href="/">Home</a> | 
                        <a href="/account">Account</a> | 
                        <a href="/logout">Log Out</a>
                    </div>
                
                </nav>
        <div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <h1>brendengerber</h1>
    <p>Name: </p>
    <p>Bio: </p>
    <p>GitHub: <a href="https://github.com/brendengerber">Link</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="six columns">
    <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/10082638?v=4" alt="Avatar">
  </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: first confirm you the value on `user.photos[0].value`. As you are serving static files through `/public` that value must starts with `/public`. Check the actual HTML code it generates, using view sourcecode. Check what is being returned through the network tab, or open the link on src (through inspect element / view source).

Comment: @SagarDevkota I have confirmed the value is what I would expect it to be by logging to the console. It's a valid url that when entered displays the image. I have also tried just typing in the URL rather than user.photos[0].value and still nothing. I have had a hard time finding an answer because most information is about images that are stored in the public directory rather than a url. I will check out the HTML using your suggestion next, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: @SagarDevkota I have added the html from source like you suggested, it seems valid. Why would it refuse to render the link when served by my app? Could it be an async issue somewhere?/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem in case anyone else runs across this issue in their learning. The problem was that the content security policy was set to self so it wasn't allowing the image from github. Adding it as an allowed source fixed the problem.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "img-src self https://avatars.githubusercontent.com");
  return next();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

first, check user obj is exsist.

and then, check user obj keys.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As stated, I even when replacing the user obj with the exact url it doesn't work, so it's not an issue with that. Thanks anyway